# How can I easily locate dungeons with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I easily locate nearby dungeons, like with the `/locate` command?

If not with vanilla, is it possible with Forge or Spigot?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/seed` to get the seed of your world and use a dungeon finder program such as [Chunkbase](https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/dungeon-finder).

Answer (score 0):

[You can't](https://www.sportskeeda.com/esports/how-find-dungeons-minecraft#:%7E:text=One%20major%20one%20is%20that,and%20gravel%20are%20still%20possible.). Your best bet is trying to find it using the sound or the knowing that it is next to a cave.

Comment: please note, this was posted before he edited it.